# How to get current location in background mode and keep sending that location to server in background mode

Tags: ios, swift

Can I send user's current location to server when app is in background. For example: In my app i want to store the user's current location in every 2min and then send his current location to server. Can I do this when the app is in background? Can I send location updates to the server in background mode and how?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit distance or accuracy, be sure background mode is checked for location in capabilities. This code work when app closed. If you want only background mode, you can set timer and send post request with UIBackgroundTask like below code.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

final class LocationManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = LocationManager()

    private var backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()    

    func startMonitoring() {
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false        
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        manager.distanceFilter = 1000.0
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
        print("LocationManager didStartMonitoringFor")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("LocationManager \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
        print("LocationManager \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        postLocation(location: locations.first)
    }
}
extension LocationManager {
    private func postLocation(location: CLLocation?) {
        guard let location = location else { return }

        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {

            backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "test_Location", expirationHandler: {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
                self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
            })

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.postRequest(location: location) { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
                    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
                }
            }
        } else {
            postRequest(location: location)
        }

    }

    private func postRequest(location: CLLocation, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
       // TODO Send Post
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either using the code above, or in response to a silent notification as recommended in the badoo article linked in the other answer. Attempting to call requestLocation or either of the request*Authorization methods causes this error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not guarantee the frequency of getting location
Significant-Change Location Service, and Monitoring Location don't wakes up your app every time

If you need get users location time to time you can use Significant-Change Location Service (of Apple Recommendations) - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service

Use `UIBackgroundTask` - for sending location, don't send location if your location don't change or change not significantly

Also this article can help you
https://badootech.badoo.com/ios-location-tracking-aac4e2323629

P.S.
Don't check this in Simulator. In my case in Simulator all work excellent, but in real device i have total problem with frequency wakes up app.
Use for debug some log file, make log too clear as can.